# IE 8 media="all" CSS issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I am experiencing a strange effect where adding media="all" to a CSS file results in a different layout of the website than having media="".

```
<link href="/webapp/css/style.css" media="" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
<link href="/webapp/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

produce the "correct" layout in IE8 and

```
<link href="/webapp/css/style.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
<link href="/webapp/css/style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

results in a different, slightly wrong layout: A 50px gap somewhere is applied.

Do any of you know of an effect similar to this one and what is the reason for this?
Might there be more to it or is this just some strange effect which can be ignored?

Thanks for your help!

Lukas

Comment: is IE rendering the page in Quirks Mode? (you can find out via the developer tools window)

Comment: nope, no Quirks Mode. It's IE8 Standards Mode in both cases.